# automation using pywinauto to click on start button

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am new to python pywinauto and I want to automate a simple step of clicking on windows start button to open control panel and selecting Administrative tools and finally want to check if the check box is checked or not. I'm stuck in the fist step of how to click on windows start button ?

Comment: Looks like a sys admin task, not a GUI automation one. Could you provide which check box and its state do you need? Maybe there is simple command line to check this setting.

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov I basically want to open printmanagement from Administrative tools.

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov How do I distinguish sys admin task and GUI automation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pywinauto import Application

Application().start(r'mmc printmanagement.msc') # Warning! it spawns child process

# connect to that child process
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe')

# print main window with the title
print(app.windows())

app.PrintManagement.dump_tree() # print identifiers for further automation
```

Comment: Hi...!!! this is just for my understanding : How did you get to know about adding " mmc " in start method and  " path='mmc.exe' " in connect ...?

Comment: The first one is quick googling, the second one is a short look at Task Manager -> tab "Details". Also `app.windows()` returned empty list if using only `start()` method.