# How to open google chrome from windows start menu using pywinauto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I am new to `pywinauto` and I want to open my own application from the windows start menu.

For this, if I come to know how to open Google chrome from the windows start menu, then I can able to handle my application.
I have gone through code mentioned in below URL but did not understand.
[automation using pywinauto to chick on start button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801164/automation-using-pywinauto-to-chick-on-start-button)

Here's the Code I tried :

```
import pywinauto.application
app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(path="explorer")
app.TaskBar.print_control_identifiers()
```

Comment: What is the reason to use "Start" menu? The executable name or command line can be found in the Start menu shortcut when you right click at your app icon and call "Properties" dialog. Also you may need to choose more proper `Application(backend="uia")` (it depends on the app). Please read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for further guidance.

Comment: If you need to check presense of the app in Start menu, it can be checked by walking corresponding folder on file system. Why overcomplicating it through GUI?

Comment: I am able to open my application by giving the full installation path.

Comment: Why Pywinauto APIS are unstable. some of the options like example "Edit" is not working all the time. Some time its fails and some times its pass. When it fails it throws "COMError : (-2147220991, 'as an event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers')

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback by editing the question? Usually such message appears when the GUI element is not in the fully initialized state. So please provide the whole error context. Every GUI may have timing issues if you're not dealing with them properly. Emotions won't help, just detailed report is always useful.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't pywinauto, but I am more experienced with pyautogui.
Type into command prompt:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Code:

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

x, y = pyautogui.position()  # gives the x and y of the bottom right corner
pyautogui.click(x, y-1)
sleep(1)  # ensure that we clicked may need to be extended for older systems
# or just pyautogui.write('win')

pyautogui.write("Google Chrome")
sleep(1) #ensure we typed it may need to be extended for older systems
pyautogui.press("enter") #press enter
```

There you go! it opens chrome in two seconds.
If you want to go to an website add this:

```
sleep(3) #google chrome takes forever to load. Just checking. Also may 
need to be extended for older systems.
pyautogui.moveTo(10, y-10)
sleep(3)
pyautogui.typewrite("URL/domain to go to", 0.25) #the 0.25 is a delay of 1/4 of a second, to bypass new chrome anti-bot protection.
sleep(12) #ensure we typed it. make sure to extend by the rule of 4 characters=add 1 also add 1 to that to make sure. this supports 40 character long URLs
pyautogui.press("enter") #press enter
```

Ok, so there you go. Just made a script to open chrome and to (optionally) go to a URL.

Comment: Could someone help me with the adding line breaks?